# Compose mail click not working in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

After login get successful in gmail, I am **not able to click** on **compose mail** button. It gives **NoSuchElementException** error.

Executemail.java

```
public void clickin(String objectname) throws Exception{    
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(prop.getProperty(objectname))));
    element.click();
}
```

keyword.java

```
if(a.get(i).equals("clickin")) {
            String Keyword = (String)a.get(i);
            String data = (String)a.get(i+1);
            String objectname = (String)a.get(i+2);
            String runmode = (String)a.get(i+3);
            System.out.println(Keyword);
            System.out.println(data);
            System.out.println(objectname);
            System.out.println(runmode);
            if(runmode.equals("Yes")) {
                key.clickin(objectname);
            }
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBSpB.png)

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: There is no error. click is working for another tags used before in the same. like login process as well. Some time it gives NullPointerException. but not everytime for same code.

Comment: Can you wait for the page to load and then perform the click action. Otherwise you can try putting a hard wait using Thread.sleep().

Comment: I alreay use explicit wait.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your locator, for me the following [XPath expression](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-xpath-selector) works fine:

```
//div[@role='button' and normalize-space()='Compose']
```

It filters the [div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) element by the `role` [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) and uses [normalize-space() function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) to ignore spaces and line breaks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My suggest would be waiting for the JS on the page to load before calling your click. I would do this with the following method - I have typed this out on my phone so sorry in advanced if any mistakes.

```
public static void waitForPageToLoad(){

    WebDriverWait wait =  new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);   
        wait.until(new  ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){
        @Override
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver){
            return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(“return document.readyState”).equals(“complete”);}});
```

`